# How to render my script after jquery validate (using Bundle Config)

Tags: asp.net, .net, bundle

I want to use validator for validation my form.

Bundle Config :

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                       "~/Scripts/script.js" // here I'm using jquery validate.
                      ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
>           at HTMLDocument. (script.js:4)
>           at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
>           at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
>           at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)

Code in my script :

```
var loginValidator = $("#loginForm").validate({...
```

It renders first jquery, validator and in the end my script. 
Why validator could not be found?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: Didn't you forget `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` in your layout after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`?

Comment: That's true :))))) I didn't see it. 
Please add your comment as an answer to mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery validate bundle into your layout, so it is not being loaded.

Try the following layout code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Note that jQuery validate should be loaded after jQuery.